# Google Sheets: Query Function with date string (same format in source and return)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to build a function where certain entries are returned based on a date and a name.

```
John 10/10/18 A A A
Joe 10/10/18 A B A
John 10/10/18 A B C
John 10/11/18 A C A
Joe 10/11/18 A C C
```

I'd like like to be able to get a Column:

```
> John - 10/10/18 1) A A A 2) A B C 3) A B C
> 
> Joe - 10/10/18 1) A B A
> 
> etc
```

My idea for this was to use unique() to find unique dates and unique names, then to use them with query.

My function would look like this:

`=query('Sample List'!$F3:AB, "select X where F = '"&A2&"' and W = '"&B2&"'"  )`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The name portion work fine, however, the second portion of the date B2 doesn't work. It's confusing because the dates are in the same exact format, so no conversion should be necessary. When I view the numbers as integers, they are exactly the same.

I've tried all sort of variations:

```
=QUERY('Sample List'!$F3:AB,"select X where W = '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
=QUERY('Sample List'!$F3:AB,"select X where W = date'"&B2&"'")
```

Yet, when the query is run, no go. Any idea on why?

Comment: what sort of a range is `$F3:AB`?  What actual range are you querying on?

Comment: Call details about what a client was calling about and so on, but the most important to me was to be able to separate the info by date & names as a separate sheet that could be then copied into an e-mail and sent out

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is there is no `string_agg()` function in google sheets, that is present in SQL for databases. This makes it harder to aggregate/group based on text values rather than numeric values in queries.

Below is a way that may help you achieve what you need. Its done in steps and you may be able to use this as a basic to make your own improvements.

Start with this in columns A to E  (in my test sheet started at row 48)

```
John    10/10/18    A   A   A
Joe     10/10/18    A   B   B
John    10/10/18    A   B   C
John    10/11/18    A   C   C
Joe     10/11/18    A   C   C
```

Using formulas `=textjoin(" ",FALSE,A48:B48)` and `=textjoin(" ",FALSE,C48:E48)`
you get this in cols A and B below.

```
John 10/10/18   A A A
Joe 10/10/18    A B B
John 10/10/18   A B C
John 10/11/18   A C C
Joe 10/11/18    A C C
```

Then below that in Col A use formula `=sort(unique(A54:A58))`

and in col B use formula `=join(" , ",filter(B$54:B$58,A$54:A$58=A60))` (drag down to copy) and you get below in Cols A and B.

```
Joe 10/10/18    A B B
Joe 10/11/18    A C C
John 10/10/18   A A A , A B C
John 10/11/18   A C C
```

Now join these columns using `=textjoin(" : ",FALSE,A60:B60)` and you get in ColA

```
Joe 10/10/18 : A B B
Joe 10/11/18 : A C C
John 10/10/18 : A A A , A B C
John 10/11/18 : A C C
```

Which is close to what you want.

In my opinion it would be better to tackle something like this in a Javascript script.

However, you may be better able to join up the various parts to reduce the steps and use arrayformula versions if you can.

Comment: Let me know if this is helpful :-)